# Creating a threadsafe, mutable, global configuration struct wrapper with C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, thread-safety

I'm trying to create a relatively simple class that stores global configuration in some serializable struct, and reads/writes from/to a file.

My main goal is to make this class easy to use correctly. While it's not a public library, there will be a sizable team using it in many parts of the codebase and I want to make it obvious to use in new code.

*Settings.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <exception>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <shared_mutex>

/// Represents global configuration based on a struct.
/// Provides abilities to load/save to a file.
///
/// @param SettingsStruct The following global overloads must exist for
/// serialization to/from streams:
///
///   ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const SettingsStruct
///   istream& operator>>(istream&, SettingsStruct&);
///
template <typename SettingsStruct>
class Settings {
 private:
  SettingsStruct settings_;
  mutable std::shared_mutex mutex_;
  std::filesystem::path filename_;

 public:
  /// Attempts to open file and initialize in-memory settings.
  Settings(std::filesystem::path filename);

  /// @note Calls Commit() before destruction
  ~Settings() { Commit(); }

  Settings(const Settings &) = delete;
  Settings &operator=(const Settings &) = delete;
  Settings(Settings &&) = delete;
  Settings &operator=(Settings &&) = delete;

  /// Commits in-memory settings to a file
  void Commit() const;

  /// @return a copy of the current settings
  SettingsStruct Get() const {
    std::shared_lock lk(mutex_);
    return settings_;
  }

  /// Safely locks + mutates the current settings based on the given transform
  /// function.
  ///
  /// @return a copy of the mutated settings
  ///
  /// @example
  ///   settings.Mutate([](auto old){ old.SomeGroup.Nested = 4.0; return old; }
  template <typename Func>
  SettingsStruct Mutate(const Func &transformFunction) {
    std::scoped_lock lk(mutex_);
    settings_ = transformFunction(settings_);
    return settings_;
  }
};

template <typename SettingsStruct>
Settings<SettingsStruct>::Settings(std::filesystem::path filename)
    : filename_(filename) {
  std::ifstream ifs(filename);
  if (ifs.is_open()) {
    ifs >> settings_;
  } else {
    std::cerr << "warning could not open settings file "
              << std::filesystem::absolute(filename);
  }
}

template <typename SettingsStruct>
void Settings<SettingsStruct>::Commit() const {
  std::scoped_lock lk(mutex_);
  std::ofstream ofs(filename_);
  ofs << settings_;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

#include "Settings.h"

using namespace std;

struct SomeGroupedSettings {
  float Nested = 0.1;  // default
  string Address = "asdf";
};

struct MySettings {
  int Version = 1;

  SomeGroupedSettings SomeGroup = {};
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const MySettings &s) {
  out << s.Version << '\n'
      << s.SomeGroup.Nested << '\n'
      << s.SomeGroup.Address << '\n';
  return out;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &in, MySettings &s) {
  in >> s.Version;
  in >> s.SomeGroup.Nested;
  in >> s.SomeGroup.Address;
  return in;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const auto filename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "config.txt";

  // clean file for testing
  {
    ofstream ofs(filename);
    if (! ofs.is_open()) return 1;
    ofs << "1\n0.5\nold_address\n";
  }

  Settings<MySettings> settings(filename);

  cout << "Loaded settings:\n" << settings.Get() << endl;

  auto a = std::async(std::launch::async, ([&]() {
                        cout << "Changing address in other thread..." << endl;
                        settings.Mutate([](auto old) {
                          old.SomeGroup.Address = "new_address";
                          return old;
                        });
                        cout << "Changed address in other thread:\n"
                             << settings.Get() << endl;
                      }));

  cout << "Changing settings in other thread..." << endl;

  settings.Mutate([](auto old) {
    old.SomeGroup.Nested = 101.3;
    old.Version = 3;
    // leave SomeGroup.Address alone
    return old;
  });

  cout << "Changed settings in main thread:\n" << settings.Get() << endl;
}
```

Example output

```
Loaded settings:
1
0.5
old_address

Changing Nested in main thread...
Changing Address in other thread...
Changed Address in other thread:
3
101.3
new_address

Changed Nested in main thread:
3
101.3
new_address
```

With *config.txt* looking like:

```
3
101.3
new_address
```

Questions/not questions:

- I will replace the `<</>>`-based serialization scheme with a parser based on [Nlohmann's JSON Library](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/features/arbitrary_types/) in the future. I'm not looking for feedback on this.
- `Get()` will be called often, while `Mutate` will be called rarely.
- Performance is not a massive concern, but obvious improvements are obviously welcome.
- The pattern for `Mutate` that I came up with (passing a mutator as an argument) doesn't seem widely used, or at least I'm not searching the right terms.

  - What are some better ways to handle mutation of shared classes?
  - Is the design of `Mutate` a terrible or particularly strange design? What are its pitfalls and why isn't it more common? I can't find much about it.
- How could I add threadsafe move operations to this? It might be useful.

Any feedback, or examples of this sort of thing in the wild, is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Design review

In summary, I don’t think this class is a good idea.

The first reason why is because it is not what it says it is. It calls itself a `Settings` class… but it has nothing at all to do with settings. It’s just a (putatively) thread-safe wrapper around some data that was read from a file. The only difference from *any* other thread-safe data wrapper is that it has a function to write the data back to the file. You could theoretically use it to read a plain string of text from a file, edit it, then write it back. (And yes, I get that `operator>>` will be replaced with a JSON parse, but that doesn’t really change the point. It would just mean that you could read any random JSON, edit it, then write it back… which is still not really a “settings” class.)

When the name of a class is wrong, it usually means that the concept is wrong, or at least badly muddled. That seems to be the case here. And when the concept is muddled, that usually means that the class is either difficult to use, or using it is inefficient. Let me illustrate.

Let’s say I want to read 3 related settings. So what is the obvious way to read 3 settings? Well, it’s something like this:

```
// assume:
// auto settings = Settings<YourActualSettingsMap>{filename};

auto setting_1 = settings.Get().setting_1;
auto setting_2 = settings.Get().setting_2;
auto setting_3 = settings.Get().setting_3;
```

Unfortunately, this very natural way of working with `Settings` is riddled with bugs and inefficiencies.

The first inefficiency is obvious: every time you call `Get()`, you copy the settings data.

Another inefficiency is much more insidious. Every time you call `Get()`, you have to acquire a lock on the internal mutex. That’s bad for efficiency, but what makes it *dangerous* is that it means that each of those three calls *could* be seeing entirely different views of the settings data.

Suppose it is very important that the 3 settings are in sync; they are all interrelated, so if one is changed, the other two usually need to be updated as well. So you read the first one… and then some other thread updates the settings data… and then you read the second one, and… well, now it is reading *new* data, so it might be out of sync with what you read for the first setting.

The problem exists on the other side, too. Once again, the natural way to update settings hides the trap:

```
settings.Mutate([](auto&& s) { s.setting_1 = "value 1"; return s; });
settings.Mutate([](auto&& s) { s.setting_2 = "value 2"; return s; });
settings.Mutate([](auto&& s) { s.setting_3 = "value 3"; return s; });
```

A naïve look at the code above would lead you to assume that you are changing the 3 settings together… but of course, since you release the lock between each call, anything could happen in between.

In both of the previous two code blocks, there is no indication at the call site that you are dealing with any locks at all. This is why it is a bad interface. You got the mantra half right: A good interface is easy to use correctly. But the important second half is: … and hard to use *incorrectly*. This interface is tricky use, and easy to use wrong.

Now, of course, you *could* rewrite both code blocks to be safe:

```
// when getting...
auto settings_view = settings.Get();
auto setting_1 = settings_view.setting_1;
auto setting_2 = settings_view.setting_2;
auto setting_3 = settings_view.setting_3;
// make sure users understand that if they make any changes to the settings
// view, they won't be saved!

// when setting...
settings.Mutate([](auto&& s) {
   s.setting_1 = "value_1";
   s.setting_2 = "value_2";
   s.setting_3 = "value_3";
   return s;
});
```

But neither of these patterns are obvious, or natural… especially the second one. You need to know the “tricks” to working with the class… you basically need to know the implementation.

There are other issues, but I’ll cover them later, throughout the review. For now, I’ll just reveal the punchline: **Hiding locks (and other synchronization) from users is always a bad idea.** At best it will be inefficient. At worst it will be dangerous.

I get it: non-concurrent code is simpler. It’s clearer, it’s easier to reason about, there are fewer traps and gotchas. I totally get the impulse to transform concurrent code into non-concurrent code. But you have to understand that when you disguise concurrent code as non-concurrent code, **all of those traps and gotchas still exist**. What’s changed is that the user is no longer aware of them. That’s not a good thing.

If some data needs to be locked, **make sure the user is aware of it**. Don’t hide the lock from them. You’re not helping them when you do that.

Here’s an alternative interface that doesn’t hide the lock:

```
// assume:
// auto settings = Settings{filename};

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// to read settings:

auto s = settings.lock();   // lock() returns a proxy object

auto setting_1 = s.get("setting-1");    // can only access settings via the
auto setting_2 = s.get("setting-2");    // locked proxy
auto setting_3 = s.get("setting-3");

// lock is released when proxy is destroyed

// won't work:
// settings.get("setting-1")    // ... need to lock to read anything
// s.set("setting-1", "value 1")    // ... lock() only gives you a read-only lock

// if you really only need a single setting:
// auto setting_1 = settings.lock().get("setting-1");

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// to set settings:

auto s = settings.lock_exclusive(); // or "lock_for_writing()" or whatever

s.set("setting-1", "value 1");
s.set("setting-2", "value 2");
s.set("setting-3", "value 3");

auto setting_1 = s.get("setting-1");    // can read from this kind of proxy

// again, lock released when proxy destroyed
```

This isn’t a *perfect* interface, because it is possible to create a deadlock by trying to acquire a lock while holding a lock. However, that’s just normal; *everyone* knows the danger of double-locking locks, and *everyone* knows that you should never hold a lock any longer than you need to, and so on. When the lock is blatant and clear in the code, normal programmer discipline can come into play. When the lock is hidden… not so much.

Incidentally, the proxy pattern means you can’t use bare `struct`s as your settings structures. That’s why I switched to function calls rather than data member accesses in the code block above. It sucks, but there’s just no practical way to do it without the proposed `operator.` or something like it. If you want to use a bare `struct`, then the lock will have to be separate from the data (unlike in the code above, where the lock and the data proxy are one and the same); that just makes things much more dangerous.

Another option is to take a cue from the “RCU”, or “read-copy-update”, pattern. Basically, you use shared pointers, and whenever you “get” the settings object to work with, you actually get a shared pointer to it. When you mutate the settings, you just mutate your own private copy of the data, and then replace the pointer in the main object:

```
// assume:
// auto settings = Settings<MySettings>{filename};
// internally, settings allocates a shared_ptr<MySettings>

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// to read settings:

auto s = settings.Get();    // returns a shared_ptr<const MySettings>
auto setting_1 = s->setting_1;
auto setting_2 = s->setting_2;
auto setting_3 = s->setting_3;

// or:
auto setting_1 = settings.Get()->setting_1;
auto setting_2 = settings.Get()->setting_2;
auto setting_3 = settings.Get()->setting_3;

// doesn't matter how many threads are reading settings; each just gets a
// pointer to the data.
//
// doesn't matter another thread *changes* the settings while you're reading,
// because you have your own private view (until the shared pointer you have
// is destructed).

// can't change the settings, because it is a pointer to const:
// settings.Get()->setting_1 = 0;   // won't compile

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// to set settings:
auto s = settings.Copy();   // allocates a NEW shared_ptr<MySettings> by
                            // copying the internal settings data

// do whatever you want safely, because you have your own copy
s->setting_1 = 0;
s->setting_2 = 0;
s->setting_3 = s->setting_1;    // can also read settings

// in order to make your changes visible to other threads, and when saving to
// file, you need to apply them:
settings.Reset(*s); // or Update() or whatever you want to call the function
```

You still need to synchronize all those shared pointer copies and resets, unless you’re using C++20 and can use `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<MySettings>>`. Pre-C++20:

```
template <typename SettingsStruct>
class Settings
{
    std::shared_ptr<SettingsStruct> p_settings_;
    mutable std::shared_mutex mutex_;
    std::filesystem::path filename_;

public:
    // ... [snip] ...

    auto Get() const
    {
        auto _ = std::shared_lock{mutex_};
        return p_settings_;
    }

    auto Copy()
    {
        auto _ = std::shared_lock{mutex_};
        return std::shared_ptr<SettingsStruct const>{p_settings_};
    }

    auto Reset(SettingsStruct const& s)
    {
        auto p = std::make_shared(s);

        auto _ = std::scoped_lock{mutex_};
        p_settings_ = p;
    }

    auto Reset(SettingsStruct&& s)
    {
        auto p = std::make_shared(std::move(s));

        auto _ = std::scoped_lock{mutex_};
        p_settings_ = p;
    }
};
```

With C++20:

```
template <typename SettingsStruct>
class Settings
{
    std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<SettingsStruct>> p_settings_;
    std::filesystem::path filename_;

public:
    // ... [snip] ...

    auto Get() const
    {
        return p_settings_.load(); // possibly with memory order acquire
    }

    auto Copy() const
    {
        // this is safe, because the owned, pointed-to object is never
        // mutated (the *pointer* is sometimes mutated (atomically, so
        // safely), but the *pointed-to data* is never mutated), so we can
        // copy it without needing to lock
        return std::make_shared<SettingsStruct>(*Get()));
    }

    auto Reset(SettingsStruct const& s)
    {
        auto p = std::make_shared<SettingsStruct>(s);

        // no problem, atomic
        p_settings_ = p;
        // or: p_settings_.store(p); // possibly with memory order release
    }

    auto Reset(SettingsStruct&& s)
    {
        auto p = std::make_shared<SettingsStruct>(std::move(s));

        // no problem, atomic
        p_settings_ = p;
        // or: p_settings_.store(p); // possibly with memory order release
    }
};
```

This pattern is actually easy to make movable, too, if you really want to. Because everyone is working with their own private view, it doesn’t really matter what you do to the main object. So long as you don’t mutate the pointed-to value (though you can replace the *pointer*, as shown), everything is safe.

### The `Mutate()` problem

The reason you probably haven’t seen the pattern you’re using for `Mutate()` very often is because it is an anti-pattern.

It is always a terrible idea to let random code execute while holding a lock. That’s what you’re doing when you allow `transformFunction` to run while `mutex_` is locked. You *assume* the user isn’t going to do anything stupid or reckless; you *assume* all they’re going to do is set some fields in the struct then return. But it is very trivial to violate your assumptions, and, worse… it’s not even that wild or silly.

For example, let’s say I want to set one setting based on the value of another:

```
settings.Mutate([](auto&& s) {
   s.value = settings.Get().other * 2; // boom
   return s;
});
```

I know you *intend* for the user to do `s.value = s.other * 2;`… but there is no way to prevent misuse, and it’s such an easy mistake to make. It could be even trickier if the code is `s.value() = calculate_value();`, and somewhere deep in the call to `calculate_value()` is a call to `Get()`.

Just don’t do it: don’t let random user code run while holding a lock.

Note that you *could* fix `Mutate()` by doing something like this:

```
template <typename Func>
SettingsStruct Mutate(const Func &transformFunction)
{
    // don't really need optional, just using it to keep the code simple
    auto s = std::optional<SettingsStruct>{};

    // copy settings, then release the lock
    {
        auto _ = std::shared_lock{mutex_};
        s = settings_;
    }

    // do the transform on the copy
    *s = transformFunction(*s);

    // now change the actual settings
    auto _ = std::scoped_lock{mutex_};
    settings_ = *s;
    return settings_;
}
```

But holy wow is that *wildly* inefficient for just changing a setting or two. This is a sign that your abstraction is wrong.

## Code review

```
#pragma once
```

[Don’t use `#pragma once`](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf8-use-include-guards-for-all-h-files). It’s ‘okay-ish’ (widely supported though non-standard) *when it works*. When it *fails*… it is absolute nightmarish catastrophe. Pray you never experience a failure of `#pragma once`.

```
  Settings(const Settings &) = delete;
  Settings &operator=(const Settings &) = delete;
  Settings(Settings &&) = delete;
  Settings &operator=(Settings &&) = delete;
```

[The convention in C++ is to put the `&` (or `&&`) with the type](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl18-use-c-style-declarator-layout).

In other words:

- ✗ `Settings &operator=(const Settings &) = delete;`
- ✓ `Settings& operator=(const Settings&) = delete;`
- ✓ `Settings& operator=(Settings const&) = delete;` (east `const` style)
- ✓ `auto operator=(Settings const&) -> Settings& = delete;` (east `const` plus trailing return)

```
  SettingsStruct Get() const {
    std::shared_lock lk(mutex_);
    return settings_;
  }
```

There is no conceivable situation where a level-headed programmer would want to call `Get()`, and *not* want to use the returned settings struct. (As opposed to, say, `Mutate()`, which also returns a copy of the settings, but a user might not care… as in your example code.) This is a good place for `[[nodiscard]]`.

```
  template <typename Func>
  SettingsStruct Mutate(const Func &transformFunction) {
    std::scoped_lock lk(mutex_);
    settings_ = transformFunction(settings_);
    return settings_;
  }
```

I mentioned above the problems that come with allowing user code to execute while holding the lock, and the hoops you have to jump through to avoid that. If you think about it logically, the only thing that actually needs to be protected by the lock is the assignment to `settings_` (except, of course, you want to pass `settings_` or a copy of it to the function first, too).

Taking the function by `const` reference is unnecessarily constraining. It “works” with simple lambdas because `operator()` is `const`-qualified by default for lambdas. But if I use a function object, or a mutable lambda, boom.

The best solution here in any case is really to just use a forwarding reference.

```
template <typename SettingsStruct>
Settings<SettingsStruct>::Settings(std::filesystem::path filename)
    : filename_(filename) {
  std::ifstream ifs(filename);
  if (ifs.is_open()) {
    ifs >> settings_;
  } else {
    std::cerr << "warning could not open settings file "
              << std::filesystem::absolute(filename);
  }
}
```

Taking the path by value is fine, since you’re storing it anyway, but once you’ve got it, you should move it rather than copying it again:

```
Settings<SettingsStruct>::Settings(std::filesystem::path filename)
    : filename_(std::move(filename)) {
```

Now, inside the constructor, you check that the file is open, which is fine… but you never check anything else. What if the settings file data is corrupt and fails to read? What if the file is fine, but there’s a disk error while reading? And even if the file *doesn’t* open, you just chug along merrily anyway. What if it really matters to me that I’ve properly read the user’s desired settings?

This is a job for exceptions. Unfortunately, you need to actually turn them on in iostreams (because they’re ancient, from pre-exception days):

```
template <typename SettingsStruct>
Settings<SettingsStruct>::Settings(std::filesystem::path filename)
    : filename_{std::move(filename)}
{
  std::ifstream ifs{filename_};
  ifs.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit);
  ifs >> settings_; // will throw if the file is not open or unreadable, or
                    // if the file's contents are corrupt
}
```

I know your ultimate goal is to use a JSON load function, so the actual details of making iostreams throw exceptions isn’t the point here. Rather, the point is about checking for and reporting errors generally. Exceptions are your only option for reporting failure from a constructor. The alternative is to have the constructor only default construct the settings, and have a separate load function which could throw or return `bool` or whatever you like. It’s probably better to have a separate load function in any case, because the user might want to refresh the settings if some external force has changed them (or they might just want to try loading a settings file, to see if it’s legit).

And finally…

```
template <typename SettingsStruct>
void Settings<SettingsStruct>::Commit() const {
  std::scoped_lock lk(mutex_);
  std::ofstream ofs(filename_);
  ofs << settings_;
}
```

There is no need to hold the lock while opening the file. Again, I know your ultimate goal is to ditch the iostreams stuff, but the points I’m making are not iostreams-specific. You should always do the *minimal* amount of work necessary while holding a lock. If your library has separate functions to open files, format data as JSON, and write files, then only the formatting part needs to be protected by the lock. Indeed, you could abandon the lock entirely at the cost of an extra copy of the data if you did:

```
template <typename SettingsStruct>
void Settings<SettingsStruct>::Commit() const {
  your_write_function(Get());

  // for example:
  //    auto ofs = std::ofstream{filename_};    // no problem if filename is never mutated
  //    ofs << Get();
}
```

The other problem is that there is no error reporting at all. How would the user know the file was opened and successfully written to? That’s kinda important to know, if only to report to the user that their settings weren’t saved.

I’m not going to review the test/example code (even though there are some dire problems with it… `using namespace std;`, and `endl`s all over the place…), because I doubt you’re interested in it.

## Summary

Hiding locks from users is evil. Don’t be evil.

Allowing arbitrary code to execute while holding a lock is extremely risky. Avoid it unless ***ABSOLUTELY*** necessary (which it absolutely isn’t in this case).

A class whose only purpose is to provide locked access to another class seems specious. I suppose it would be possible if one could write proper general proxy objects in C++… but you can’t. (A proper general proxy object might have an overloaded `operator.` that just calls the wrapped class’s `operator.` while locked… but we don’t have overloadable `operator.`, so… .)

So you have to give up the dream of `Settings<SettingsStruct>` working with any random `SettingsStruct` type. Either make `Settings` specific to one specific `SettingsStruct` type, or use an interface… which will limit which types you can use as `SettingsStruct`, but still allow some options, although you won’t be able to support bare `struct`s that only have data members.

Comment: I agree to most of it (I think I was trying to kinder in my review but perhaps this is better). I do not agree with the overall assessment though. I know it is _very_ difficult to come up with very secure design even with best intentions (`auto_ptr`) mainly because the C++ deals with new language features. They seem to go on adding new things which ends up being more difficult to have perfect design. I am not fan of documentation because it doesn't keep up with code but perhaps giving _very_ limited API with strong warning in doc might help. Just a thought

Comment: Fantastic info about API design especially, thank you. I am slowly abandoning my dream of allowing arbitrary structs as configs. Maybe string keys is the simpler way. What are the pitfalls of using the proxy-object method, but overloading `operator->` or just a `Get()` method that returns a reference to the underlying `struct` from the proxy? Would it be unsafe because you can copy the reference outside of the proxy's lifetime?

Comment: Tried it out. The temporary lifetime of the proxy object in the method call makes things like `settings.Lock()->Version++` unsafe.

Comment: Great review, as usual.  One thing you missed mentioning from `Commit()` is that it _truncates the file before starting to write_.  So if anything goes wrong during the write, _we no longer even have the last good version_.  I hate it when programs lose their settings for no apparent reason (Qt Assistant, I'm looking at you!).

Comment: The RCU pattern seems great, but it does suffer from two threads erasing each others changes if they both try the Copy/Reset at the same time. I guess it would be unlikely, though.

Comment: I also found this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328100787_TOWARDS_A_HIGH-LEVEL_C_ABSTRACTION_TO_UTILIZE_THE_READ-COPY-UPDATE_PATTERN which has an interesting implementation here: https://github.com/martong/rcu_ptr. It doesn't seem to suffer from obvious deadlock scenarios but does let you pass in a lambda to copy-and-update.

Comment: Yeah, just skimmed the paper, but it looks like it’s using the same pattern for mutation that I suggested above: first (either under lock or atomically) copy the data, update the copy, then (locked/atomically) replace old data with the new data. Safe, but not very efficient, and of course it also has the issue of one thread’s changes being completely “lost” when another thread’s changes take (but that’s hard to avoid in *any* concurrently shared data scheme; before writing your changes, you’d have to poll for other changes, and then “merge”… the inefficiencies just keep adding up).

Answer (score 2):

> `SettingsStruct Get() const {`

You do not need to return copy. If someone want to *make*  copy, they can still do it even if you return const SettingsStruct&. Returning copy would affect performance (a lot if `Get` is called way too many times)

> The pattern for Mutate that I came up with (passing a mutator as an argument) doesn't seem widely used, or at least I'm not searching the right terms. I

The reason probably you did not come across many because eventually they would become difficult to maintain. You are giving access to a some function which may be changing state that would affect `Settings` object. If you are going to provide this to limited number of users, it would be fine I am sure.

> What are some better ways to handle mutation of shared classes?

I am sure you are realize that in a way you are giving templated serialization version for a file, any file. Nothing wrong with that; just that if you wanted you could look at some serialization frameworks for inspiration. I wouldn't call them better just different.

> Is the design of Mutate a terrible or particularly strange design? What are its pitfalls and why isn't it more common? I can't find much about it.

No, it not terrible design at all. It is useful. All you need to remember is, there is very little you can do to have specific restrictions on what it may or may not do. For example, what happens if it throws? Do you want to change the accepted signature to `noexcept`? Is `Mutate` reentrant?

> How could I add threadsafe move operations to this? It might be useful.

I would suggest you get this one out first, let some people use it before adding more capabilities. You would get better feedback (from yourself if you not from others).

One additional feedback:

> `void Settings<SettingsStruct>::Commit() const {`

This should not be constant. The reason why it *can* be constant is because you are not changing data that is owned by the class but you are doing much more. You are changing *underlying storage*. User of the class should have very clear boundary of what he can or cannot do.

Comment: Get *has* to return a copy. If you return a reference, you expose the internal data without a lock. That kinda defeats the whole point of the class.

Comment: @indi You are taking responsibility of something that you should not take. It's job of the developer of `SettingStruct` to allow or disallow access. Yours is just to make sure that when it is accessed in the __way you intended__ you don't give incorrect write access. Or this class becomes too tightly coupled with `SettingStruct`s. Imagine having huge amount of data in that struct. Every time you copy, you are going to increase overhead.

Comment: That makes no sense. If `SettingStruct` is already thread-safe, then this entire class has no point. If it is not thread-safe, then you can’t return a reference. So `Get()` either *has* to return a copy, or the whole `Settings` class should be thrown out. This is not a question of efficiency or overhead, it is a question of correctness.

Comment: @vish I believe what indi is trying to say is that the copying from reference will not be under mutex lock, so not atomic. Other thread may modify the data before the copy constructor finishes execution.

Comment: @indi I am not asking to return by reference I am asking to return by _const_ reference. You can still make _copy_ if you want to, is it not? Incomputable, does that make sense?

Comment: You’re still missing the point. Consider `auto x = settings.Get();` with a `const&` return like you want. This does: 1) acquire lock; 2) create `const&` to `_settings`; 3) return `const&` to `_settings`; 4) release lock; 5) copy `_settings` to `x` **but uh oh you’re copying `_settings` after you lost the lock!!!** Between 4 and 5, another thread starts mutating `_settings`, and you do the copy while the object is half-mutated. Boom, undefined behaviour (maybe a hard crash, if you’re lucky). Get it now?

Comment: @indi okay, I agree. That is the problem with API not with the requirement. You cannot return a copy. If you are calling this `Get` multiple times then it's performance is going to unacceptable. The lifetime of ` SettingsStruct` object is managed by `Settings`. So, I would suggest OP does two things: 1. Remove `Get` 2. Rename `Mutate` to `Access`